# How to control fps on video without using JMF in Java

Tags: java

I'm about to write a program that can take .rgb video file as input, and specify his fps and play it out. But how can I meet this purpose without using JMF package, because I think the meaning of this program is to know how the frame-by-frame works, so I decide it to use BufferedImage as my tool to implement this program, but I still not figure it out how it works on the video (frame-by-frame).

here's the starter code that TA gave us:
I try lots of things, but the delay between two frames is very obvious, I don't know why. is there any efficiency way to play the video frame-by-frame without using any JMF package.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class imageReader {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = args[0];
        int width = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        try {
            File file = new File(fileName+".rgb");
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            //BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            long len = file.length();  //bytes in one frame (consist of R,G,B frame)
            byte[] bytes = new byte[10000000];

            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }
            System.out.println("\noffset = "+ offset);   //7603200
            System.out.println("numRead = "+ numRead);   //7603200
            System.out.println("file length: " + len);   //7603200
            System.out.println("frame #: "+ (offset/(width*height*3))); //100

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();  
            frame.setVisible(true);

            int ind = 0;
            int f = 1;

            while(ind < offset){
                for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){

                    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){

                        byte a = 0;
                        byte r = bytes[ind];
                        byte g = bytes[ind+height*width];
                        byte b = bytes[ind+height*width*2]; 

                        int pix = 0xff000000 | ((r & 0xff) << 16) | ((g & 0xff) << 8) | (b & 0xff);
                        //int pix = ((a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b);
                        img.setRGB(x,y,pix);
                        ind++;
                    }
                }
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));  
                frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
                frame.pack();  
                System.out.println("frame #: "+ ind);
            }

            System.out.print("end");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Use a label to display the image
        /*JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         *JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
         *frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         *frame.pack();
         *frame.setVisible(true);
         **/

    }

}
```

What is going wrong with this code??